# Compute $\oint_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}dz$, using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> The question is how to compute the integral
>   $$\int_{\partial D} \frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}dz\qquad D=\{z \in C : |z|<3\}$$

I find two essential singularities at $z=0$ and $z=2$, and a pole of order $1$ at $z=5$. For the Residues Theorem $$\int_{\partial D}f(z) dz=2\pi i \sum_{k=0}^{n} Res(f(z),z_k) $$ Now the problem is that, to find the residues at $z=0$ and $z=2$, I should calculate the Laurent Series of $f$ at $ z_0=0$ and $z_1=2$ and find the terms $a_{-1}$. How could I proceed?

Comment: Maybe this is a case to do by computing the singularities *outside* the curve, including at $\infty$.

Comment: i second the idea of @GEdgar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R>5$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}\,dz&=\int_{|z|=R}\frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}\,dz\\\\
&-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}, z=5 \right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

Since, $\sin(1/z)=O(1/R)$ and $\cos(1/(z-2))=O(1/R)$ as $R\to \infty$, then the integral over the circle $|z|=R$ vanishes as $R\to \infty$.  Hence, we find immediately that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}\,dz&=-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\sin(1/z)\cos(1/(z-2))}{z-5}, z=5 \right)\\\\
&=-2\pi i \sin(1/5)\cos(1/3) 
\end{align}$$